# Getting access to window object in JSM

Tags: javascript, xpcom

I am creating a firefox extension.  I want to get a reference to the window object in a JSM file.
The file is then imported using

```
Components.utils.import("resource://js/my_module.jsm");
```

In my_module.jsm there is this line:

```
var jQenv = window.content.document;
```

which throws the error, "window is not defined"

How can I get access to the window object in the JSM file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get access to the window object that you want, [see this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#From_a_dialog).

Comment: thank you.  I found stuff on how to get alert defined within the jsm.  This is what I was looking for to get the window defined within the jsm :)

Comment: Well, to be able to do an alert, you could just use nsIPromptService.

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code from my addon, Power Bookmarks:

```
gBrowser.contentDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML+="<div id=\"powerbookmarks.div\" style=\"background-color: black; padding-left: 2px; z-index: 9999; opacity: 0.8; width: 100% !important; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; height: 45px !important; color: white !important;\">Content removed to keep it short</div>";
```

That will get you access to the current body element and `gBrowser.contentDocument` might be the window where `.documentElement` is the actual document.

You can view the code in context at: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/92549 by clicking on chrome > content > overlay.js

I hope this helps

Comment: within the JSM file, gBrowser is not defined